# Swift @IBDesignable - @IBInspectable multiple variables

Tags: ios, swift2, ibdesignable

I am trying to create a custom class for `UILabel` so I can see the result from the Storyboard. I need to change the text attributes in order to create an outline label.

With the code I have so far I can manage to do this however I can only add one variable.

If I had multiple `var` I get the following errors.

```
> 'var' declarations with multiple variables cannot have explicit
> getters/setters 'var' cannot appear nested inside another 'var' or
> 'let' pattern Getter/setter can only be defined for a single variable
```

How can I use multiple variables?
CODE:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomUILabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var outlineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0, var outlineColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {


                let strokeTextAttributes = [
                    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : outlineColor,
                    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -1 * outlineWidth,
                    ]

                self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Just put them in separate lines and annotate each as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment - you need to have each variable in separate lines. This means that you need to have `didSet` declared for both of them. Something like this :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomUILabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var outlineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setAttributes(self.outlineColor, outlineWidth: self.outlineWidth)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var outlineColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.setAttributes(self.outlineColor, outlineWidth: self.outlineWidth)
        }
    }

    func setAttributes(outlineColor:UIColor, outlineWidth: CGFloat) {
        let strokeTextAttributes = [
            NSStrokeColorAttributeName : outlineColor,
            NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -1 * outlineWidth,
            ]

        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I have tried this however, I can only see and change `outlineWidth` in the Attribute inspector

Comment: doing copy and paste did not work.. Writing your code worked perfect

Comment: Why if I update the text in the code the text attributes are not saved?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some code ;) but you have to remember that `text` and `attributedText` are separate properties of `UILabel`. This basically means that each time you want to set new text and retain the attributes you need to create new `NSAttributedString` with them.

Comment: thank you.. In order to change the text attributes for a new string I have to call after setAttributes function